# nesting json objects in a for loop

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

I have a for loop, it returns an id and the name of all the images a user has.

```
 $from1 = 1;
 $from2 = 10;

 for ($i=$from1; $i < $from2; $i++) {
     if (($i % 5) == 0) 
     $idTemp = $id1[$i];

     echo $idTemp;
     echo $name[$i];
 }
```

Instead of echoing out the data, I wish to place it into a json response, like this:

```
"images":[
    "1":{"id":"1234","name":"thisisaname"},
    "2":{"id":"4332","name":"namename"}
]
```

But i can't seem to work out how to create json arrays inside a loop. Also how would i then loop through to decode the json?

Can anyone help?
Cheers for any help in advance, Jamie

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the server side (PHP) to print the json response, first create the php array that has the same structure, then you can encode it with `json_encode`:

```
$from1 = 1;
$from2 = 10;

$json = array('images' => array());
for ($i=$from1; $i < $from2; $i++) {
    if (($i % 5) == 0) {
        $json['images'][$i] = array(
            'id' => $id1[$i],
            'name' => $name[$i]
        );
     }
}

echo json_encode($json);
```

On the client side (JS) you will receive say a `data` object:

```
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    for (x in data.images) {
        data.images[x].id;
        data.images[x].name;
    }
}
```